# Details: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset

Tags: networking, oracle11g, ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty

I am trying to deploy the configuration and runtime using IBM Mobilfirst Server Configuration Tool for the server configuration, and I end up with a connection reset error. The error from the logfiles is 
    Cannot access database: ServiceName.
    Details: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset.
Kindly help in resolving this issue.
Which part is throwing the error? Is it DB side? Network Connectivity?

Comment: What is Web configuration Tool? When do you see this error? Is it during installation or after? The message is clear - your DB is resetting the connection. Verify your DB configuration

Comment: Sorry for the wrong terminologies used.

Comment: This issue arises post installation at the time of deployment of configuration and runtime using server configuration tool. Am able to deploy the configuration if I use the DB name, But am getting a connection reset error when am trying using the Service name.

Comment: I think you should edit your question to make it more readable and also have the right problem statement - specifically the fact that it works with DB name and not the service. Connection Reset is thrown by the DB when the configuration tool is trying to communicate with it. You need to check with your DBA if the service name is correct or if there is some problem reaching the DB by that name

Comment: Am able to connect to the DB through Toad(tool) using both service name as well as DB name.

Comment: Can you try a Java program to do that ? See what output you get

Comment: Am getting connected to the DB with the java code. My doubt is how do the server configuration tool understands whether the given name is a DB name or its Service Name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ServerConfig Tool (SCT) creates the URL first by considering that the database name as SID. If the connection fails, it then connects using the database name as a service name.

I see that you are seeing the error - 'Cannot access database: ServiceName. Details: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error'.

When SCT notices an unknown error while connecting it stops the connection process with the above error.

I would recommend you to run the ANT tasks for configuring MFP to get detailed logs on why configuration is failing.

Comment: Thanks for your Information. Could you please guide me with the steps in running the ant scripts and getting the logs

Comment: Configuration is already deployed using the DB name,but the runtime is not getting deployed, here am using the Service name.

Comment: Running the ant Scripts from the console really worked. Am able to deploy the configuration and runtime sucessfully.